# Unwanted separation marks / lines between assembled ggplots using {patchwork}

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I'm trying to combine plots with "grey20" as the plot background.
However, while combining plots, an unwanted behavior seems to be happening as a lighter separation line appears between the top plot and the bottom plots.

Does someone know whether this comes from a mistake on my part, or whether there is a workaround to avoid this unpleasant behavior ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Best,

```r
# plotA

plotA <- plot_spacer()+ theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20"))

  
# plotB

plotB <- plot_spacer()+ theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20"))
  
  
# plotC
  
plotC <- plot_spacer()+ theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20"))
                              
# Combining plots

(plotA / (plotB + plotC )) + plot_layout(heights = c(1,.1))
```

Edit -
Although it does seem that the issue came from my specific graphic device setup as this problem did not occur while using R directly (instead of RStudio), the issue was corrected anyway with the following added element piece of code :

```r
((plotA / (plotB + plotC )) + plot_layout(heights = c(1,.1))) & theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce these seperation lines with patchwork v1.1.1 and ggplot2 v3.3.3.9000 (dev version) on RStudio in windows with the AGG backend for the graphics device.

Comment: Thank you for your message -  I am using patchwork v1.1.1 and ggplot2 v3.3.3 on RStudio in MacOS - the situation occurs for me whether in the viewer pane, in R Markdown or after having saved the plot, but surprisingly, does not occur when I run the code directly in R...

Comment: @teunbrand I can reproduce this, with same packages as the OP. Not everyone has the dev version of ggplot installed ;), but I guess it's more the agg device that you use.

Comment: Henri, please add your edit rather as an answer. Please don't delete the question as it will help others to solve similar issues.

Comment: It actually occurs only when adding the heights as specs. funny

Comment: @tjebo Do you mean to tell me that people are not running possibly unstable versions of ggplot2 for those juicy improvements in error messaging? :O (just kidding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit -

Thank you all for your answers, the situation is now solved !

I understand three things from this situation :

1. The graphic device setup can have an influence on the end result (this problem did not occur when I was using R directly instead of RStudio)
2. The heights argument seems to be the cause of the situation
3. Either way, adding the following piece of code solves it all (here, specifying that the plot background for all three *patchworked* should be colored and filled the way each individual plot is) :

```
((plotA / (plotB + plotC )) + plot_layout(heights = c(1,.1))) & theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20")
```

Best,

Henri

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but to demonstrate reproducibility.

This occurs when height argument is given. As the OP states, it disappears when passing the theme globally.

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)
p <-
  replicate(2, list(
    plot_spacer() + 
      theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey20",color = "grey20"))))

wrap_plots(p, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

```r
wrap_plots(p, nrow = 2, heights = c(1,.1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#>  os       macOS Big Sur 10.16         
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_GB.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/London               
#>  date     2021-04-04                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.3   2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  patchwork   * 1.1.1   2020-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
```